# SQL JOIN : Help using join inisted subquery

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables,

The first one is called emp, and has 2 columns called id and name

The second one is called dep, and has columns called id and empid and nameOfDep

if I want to list all emp that have X dep, but don't have Y dep

This is an example I use

```
Select e.id, e.name
from emp e
where e.id in (Select empid from deptid where deptid=X)
and e.id not in (Select empid from deptid where deptid=Y);
```

How I can make it using JOIN instead of with subqueries?

Comment: how can a row have deptid=X AND deptid=Y at the same time?

Comment: There is some typo in your query: at first you mention a table name dep with the column nameOfDep then in your query there is deptid as both table and column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IN can be converted into an INNER JOIN. A Not IN can be converted to LEFT JOIN / NULL Test. Sometimes called an ANTI JOIN.

```
SELECT e.id, 
       e.name 
FROM   emp e 
       INNER JOIN deptid D_X 
               ON e.empid = d_x.empid 
                  AND deptid = 'X' 
       LEFT JOIN deptid D_Y 
              ON e.empid = d_Y.empid 
                 AND deptid = 'Y'
WHERE  d_Y.empid IS NULL
```

Also I'm making the assumption that when you wrote `deptid = X` that you meant X to be a literal string and not a field name

Comment: Thanks :) can you help me to understand this query in venn diagram؟

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT e.id, e.name
FROM emp e
INNER JOIN dep d ON (e.deptID = d.deptID AND d.deptID NOT y)
```

Add the Department ID to the employee record and then join on that.

**EDIT**
My bad, updated.

**EDIT**
Helps to read, go with Conrad's answer.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. He has additional conditions.

Comment: Yeah, you're still not meeting all conditions.